# How to autogenerate id when I have defined id uint64 `bson:"_id"`

Tags: mongodb, go

Let's say you have a simple struct

```
type User struct {
    ID              uint64    `json:"id" bson:"_id"`
    UserName        string    `json:"user_name" bson:"userName"`
    Email           string    `json:"email" bson:"email"`
}

u := User{
    userName: "me",
    Email:    "me@mail.com"
}
```

I am trying to insert this object in MongoDB collection like so:

```
r, err := collection.InsertOne(context.TODO(), u)
```

The `ID` field here has a value of 0 because I didn't specify a value.
The problem is that MongoDB does not auto-generate the `_id` field but instead, sets the value to equal 0, which is very logical but not the outcome I would like.

Is there a way to auto-generate the `_id` with this method?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `omitempty` tag on `ID`.

```
type User struct {
    ID              primitive.ObjectID    `json:"id" bson:"_id,omitempty"`
    UserName        string    `json:"user_name" bson:"userName"`
    Email           string    `json:"email" bson:"email"`
}
```

If you don't specify the `omitepmty` tag, then the behaviour is as specified on [Go structs](https://gobyexample.com/structs); whereby if any of struct fields are omitted it will be zero-valued.

In this case because you have specified the field type to be [primitive.ObjectID](https://pkg.go.dev/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson/primitive?tab=doc#ObjectID), `ObjectId('000000000000000000000000')` is the zero value.

Hence you need to generate an ID when you create the struct:

```
collection.InsertOne(context.TODO(), 
                     User{ ID: primitive.NewObjectID(), 
                           UserName: "me", 
                           Email: "me@mail.com"})
```

Comment: even with the omitempty tag, it didn't work. Also, I can't assign the value primitive.NewObject() to the ID even if I do it like this uint64(primitive.NewObject())

Comment: I also tried to bson.Marsal() the struct but that also didn't work. I still doesn't omit the id

Comment: ן fixed the type in the struct, it's suppose to be `primitive.ObjectID`and not `uint64`